# Why not build lists in-order? (instead of pushing to the front & reversing)

Tags: list

In emacs-lisp a common pattern is to build a list by adding to the font, then reversing it.

As it's possible to build the list by storing the last cons cell, then appending to it - it seems like a reasonable way of building lists (in-order).

This snippet shows both being done with rough times:

```el
(require 'benchmark)

(message
  "Build & reverse time: %S (seconds)"
  (benchmark-elapse
   (let ((ls (list)))
     (dotimes (n 20000000)
       (push n ls))
     (setq ls (nreverse ls)))))

(message
  "Build in-order time: %S (seconds)"
  (benchmark-elapse
   (let* ((ls (list nil))
          (ls-tail ls))
     (dotimes (n 20000000)
       (setq ls-tail (setcdr ls-tail (cons n nil))))
     (setq ls (cdr ls)))))
```

Interpreted:

```
Build & reverse time: 19.099104894 (seconds)
Build in-order time: 18.211213415 (seconds)
```

Compiled (emacs 29/master)

```
Build & reverse time: 2.630210386 (seconds)
Build in-order time: 2.461847862 (seconds)
```

- Are there ways to do this without dealing directly with cons cells? (a macro for example that hides low-level cons cell manipulation?).
- Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: DId you repeat the measurements? Do you get consistent results when you do that? I just did one run and I got 18s in the build/reverse case and 20s in the in-order case (there is an extra paren on the penultimate line of that one BTW). Repeating it on my ancient desktop, I get 64s in the first case, 84s in the second case. What is the argument *for* doing it in order?

Comment: Yes, the measurements are around the same each run. Tested with emacs 29 (master) in-order builds are consistently faster.

Comment: re: `What is the argument for doing it in order?` Logically it's less computation as your only visiting each item once, reversing needs to rebuild the list in the reverse direction.

Comment: I would say that both are OK to use. Most importantly, they use the same amount of cons cells (since `nreverse` does the reverse destructively by reusing existing cons cells). Personally, I would pick the `nreverse` solution since the code is easier to write, read, and debug. Code that plays around with `setcdr` always make be uneasy, since it's easy to misunderstand subtle details.